# Record audio while is touching a button like messenger, wpp or even allo react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need a button in the UI, which when you keep it pressed, it records audio. How I do that in React native? How can I record audio of that way?

[image]

Note: I need support for Android as iOS.

Comment: Does the picture help?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options. You can either implement it yourself by bridging code for both Android and iOS and using their native modules. The second option is to use a pre-existing component [react-native-record-sound](https://github.com/MisterAlex95/react-native-record-sound) which will give you the ability to record audio for both android and iOS. By the way, node package manager is a great resource for looking up react-native components if you ever are wondering if one exists in the future.